# Avoid hyperref border inside Tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, cross-referencing, labels

I want to add a rotated legend to my tikz figure. I'm able to do so using `ylabel`, but because this relies on `\ref{}`, the `hyperref` package adds a red border to my figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel={\ref{labelname} Data}]

\addplot coordinates {(1,2)(2,1.5)(3,2.5)(4,1)};  \label{labelname}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can this border be removed without removing all other hyperref-related borders?

Comment: Keep the preamble the same and change your `tikzpicture` environment to:

`\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begingroup
 \hypersetup{hidelinks}
 \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel={\ref{labelname} Data}]
  \addplot coordinates {(1,2)(2,1.5)(3,2.5)(4,1)};  \label{labelname}
 \end{axis}
 \endgroup
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Perfect! If I hover over that place I can still see a highlighted area, but if I move the cursor elsewhere it's hidden. That's good enough, the red box was always visible and annoying. Thank you!

Comment: How about changing the `ylabel` to `ylabel={\ref*{labelname} Data}`?

Comment: @M.AlJumaily That was embarrassingly simple. If you post that as the answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to locally change the setup of hyperref to get rid of the border:

```
\begingroup
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\begin{axis}
  ...
\end{axis}
\endgroup
```

and `\ref*{...}` instead of `\ref{...}` to disable the clickable region.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel={\ref{labelnameone} Data}]
        \addplot coordinates {(1,2)(2,1.5)(3,2.5)(4,1)};  \label{labelnameone}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begingroup
    \hypersetup{hidelinks}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={\ref*{labelnametwo} Data}]
        \addplot coordinates {(1,2)(2,1.5)(3,2.5)(4,1)};  \label{labelnametwo}
    \end{axis}
    \endgroup
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel={\ref{labelnamethree} Data}]
        \addplot coordinates {(1,2)(2,1.5)(3,2.5)(4,1)};  \label{labelnamethree}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I cannot quite reproduce your picture: For me, the line below "Data" in the third figure is blue, just as in the other two figures. The third code is exactly the same as the first one, did you mean to change something?

Comment: @Christopher, sorry! I have updated the output.